# How not to wait for other threads in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am considering using OpenMP for multithreading in C++. But I wonder if there is a way tell a thread not to wait for other concurrent thread and continue with my program? (Maybe I can cancel/kill other threads?)

I am aware of the existence of "nowait" clause, but I want the decision of "wait" or "not to wait" to be done dynamically (The program will decide depending on results of the process I am doing).

I hope I can get some advices on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd would do it something along the lines of

```
if(conditon)
{
     taskA_with_Barriers();
}  
else
{
     taskA_without_Barrier();
}
```

The `condtion` needs to be the same constant through out all threads.

If you need to be canceling Threads you might be using the wrong technolgy.  Might also want to take a look at *pthreads* or *MPI*.

Comment: @nacho4d if you are using C++, it makes more sense to use boost threads.  OpenMP maybe very limiting in what you can do